# Search Function in Symfony2 is not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a project using symfony framework. I just want to make a simple search function wherein it can search all the entities that contain with what the user inputted. When I tried to run my code, its not working it keeps on redirecting to my no found result even if their is a related files to be found with.

Here is my controller:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $data = $request->request->get('search');


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
                'SELECT a,b,c
                FROM SampleBundle:transactionDetail a
                JOIN a.transaction b
                JOIN b.documentRelated c
                WHERE a.pNumber LIKE :data
                AND b.senderId LIKE :data
                AND b.receiverId LIKE :data
                AND b.transactDate LIKE :data
                AND a.amountPaid LIKE :data')
                ->setParameter('data',$data);  

        $res = $query->getResult();
        if($res == null){
                return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:noresult.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('SampleBundle:Sample:search.html.twig', array('res' => $res));
    }
```

and  for my search.html.twig

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block pageTitle %} Related Files Found{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

div class="table-responsive margins" >
  <table  class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover no-margin">
      <thead>
        <tr style="height: 40px; ">
        <th>Transaction Date</th>       
        <th>Sender ID</th> 
        <th>Receiver ID</th>
        <th>P Number</th> 
        <th>Amount Paid</th> 

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>    
        {% for res in res %}         
          {% for other in res.transaction %}
         <td >{{res.transaction.transactDate|date('YMd')}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{res.ediTransaction.transactionDate|date('H:i')}}</td>
          <td>{{res.transaction.senderId}}</td>
          <td >{{res.transaction.receiverId}}</td>

          {% if other.pNumber != null %}
            <td style="word-break: break-all">{{other.pNumber}}</td> 
          {% else %}
            <td>N/A</td>
          {% endif %}
          {% if other.amountPaid != null %}
             <td style="word-break: break-all">{{other.amountPaid}}</td>    
          {% else %}
            <td>N/A</td>
          {% endif %}

      </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
  {% javascripts
    'bundles/sampledoc/js/jQuery.js'
    'bundles/sampledoc/js/bootstrap.js'
     %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

my form for searching:

```
<form action="{{path('sample_search')}}" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group input-group">
    <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" style="width: 200px; float: right;" >
      <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" style="margin-right: 20px;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Can somebody help me with this one? thanks in advance.

Comment: did you cross check if your query is actually returning results? If you do `dump($res)` do you see any output?

Comment: this is the result: array(0) { }

Comment: I don't have any errors now but still its not working... my url look like this

Comment: http://localhost:2224/Track/web/app_dev.php/search?search=117709

Comment: anybody who have idea, can you help me?

Comment: You don't have to write `$request = $this->getRequest();` because you pass it already as a method argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data can't equal all your criteria. If you AND everything in your query data has to match all fields, so you will probably return no results.

Try something like:

```
WHERE a.pNumber LIKE :data
OR b.senderId LIKE :data
OR b.receiverId LIKE :data
OR b.transactDate LIKE :data
OR a.amountPaid LIKE :data')
->setParameter('data', "%$data%");
```

And look at the generated SQL with

```
$query->getSQL()
```

This way you can actually test your query directly on the DB.

Comment: it gives me an error : Controller "Matrix\MatrixEdiBundle\Controller\MatrixController::searchAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$sender_id" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

Comment: $sender_id isn't present in your example code, that's a separate issue from your SQL problem.

Comment: Yes, I think you must have added $sender_id to the signature of searchAction() since you posted the code above, if you are getting that error.

Comment: I fix it already, but when I search it doesn't display the related files found. why is that so?

Comment: where can I possibly put the $query->getSQL() ?

Comment: how about if I also put pagination on the result of my search? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $data is an associative array holding all the goodies, I do not think you can just hand it to setParameter() the way you are doing.  You need to break it down more specifically, for each of those "LIKE" clauses.

Completely untested but I suspect you are looking for something like:

```
`
WHERE a.pNumber LIKE :pNumber
AND b.senderId LIKE :senderId
AND b.receiverId LIKE :recieveId
AND b.transactDate LIKE :transactDate
AND a.amountPaid LIKE :amountPaid')
->setParameters(array(
    'pNumber' => $data['pNumber'],
    'receiverId'   => $data['receiverId'],
    'transactDate' => $data['transactDate'],
    'amountPaid'   => $data['amountPaid'],
));
`
```

Comment: Also, if I understand what you are doing here, I strongly recommend checking out https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle

Comment: it gives me an error : Warning: Illegal string offset 'pNumber'

Comment: where should I place my form in order for me to get the correct data I search?